# GC causing brief browser freeze; memory leak?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a ~300 line javascript file that appears to be leaking memory, which periodically causes brief browser freezing due to what I believe is garbage collection.

This is my first attempt at writing JS, so my assumptions are pretty much guesses based on what I've been researching and using Chrome's Timeline and other tools.

Here's a very simplified version that reproduces the problem. I am positive I have other code in the script that's broken, but I think if I can get some pointers of what I may be doing wrong here, I'll be able to apply any changes to the rest of the code.

Can someone please help me understand what I could possibly do different to prevent the problem? If it's relevant, the backend I'm using to pull data from is Perl's `Dancer2`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var temp_limit = -1;
    var humidity_limit = -1;

    event_interval();

    function event_interval(){
        $.get('/get_config/event_display_timer', function(interval){
            interval = interval * 1000;
            setInterval(display_env, interval);
        });
    }

    function display_env(){
        $.get('/fetch_env', function(data){
            var json = $.parseJSON(data);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Does `'/fetch_env'` complete faster or slower than `interval`ms? It is possible that you have set up a cascade

Comment: In Chrome there are tools to profile your code. This might be helpfull https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/rendering-tools/

Comment: @PaulS. I just changed the `fetch_env` route to return the data immediately with no processing at all, so the problem persists when I guarantee that the call to `fetch_env` return happens long before the interval expires.